# Error BC30456: 'ElementAtOrDefault' is not a member of 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow)'

Tags: vb.net, iis, ashx

The compiler on the server throws the error "'ElementAtOrDefault' is not a member of 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection(Of System.Data.DataRow)'" at the line:
    `Dim dr As DataRow = clientDataTable(0)`
in my .ashx file. It also threw this error when I previously tried
    `Dim strFirstName As String = clientDataTable(0)("FirstName").ToString()`
Am I declaring the DataRow incorrectly, or is there something else I'm missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
clientDataTable.Rows(0)
```

Rather than just using (clientDataTable(0)) this will make sure you actually get rows back.